# Is there a way to capture events emitted by multiple child components in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent component which has multiple child components

```
<grid>
   <cell></cell>
   <cell></cell>
   <cell></cell>
</grid>
```

My cell components emit an event with payload saying it is being edited
`this.$emit('editing',cellId)`

I know I can capture the event like 
`<cell @editing="do something"></cell>` or capture using `EventBus.$on('editing')`, I do not want to use root listener as well `this.$root.$on('editing')`

But because its the parent component, how can i listen to event of 'editing' when the parent component is mounted

```
mounted: function(){
    this.$on('editing',dosomething)
}
```

why am I not able to add listen when the parent component is mounted?

Comment: Your `mounted` function is listening for events on the parent component. The child components emit events on themselves. What is your goal, and why do you not want to do the `<cell @editing="...">` form of event handling?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're aiming for. Please clarify your goal if possible. But if you want to listen for `editing` event in parent component, you can use EventBus in mounted hook: `EventBus.$on('editing')`

Comment: I wanted to conceptually understand this and how events in child work. The best way i know is `<cell @editing="..."` without using eventBus or emitting to $root

so what is the difference between listening in `mounted` and listening on component `@editing`

Comment: @RoyJ - I don't think this is correct: `Your mounted function is listening for events on the parent component`. You cannot emit events to children, it happens with `props` instead. The `mounted` function actually listens for events *inside the current instance*.

Comment: @AndreyPopov The current instance is the parent component. I am using "parent" to distinguish between his parent and child components, not between the component I'm talking about and its parent.

Comment: Oh, okay, sounds legit then :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference that you are missing is described in the [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) section:

> In addition, a parent component can listen to the events emitted from a child component using v-on directly in the template where the child component is used.
>
> You **cannot use $on to listen to events emitted by children**. You *must* use v-on *directly* in the template, as in the example below.

What this means is that child-parent communication is done through a *directive*, using the `v-on` (or `@edit`) way.

Your example here

```
mounted: function(){
    this.$on('editing',dosomething)
}
```

Won't actually work. In the [emit documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) it's said that:

> Trigger an event on the current instance.

Which means that *inside the same* component, you can actually use `this.$on` and it will work. But if you want to use it in parent, then you should use the inline directive to have it bind, otherwise it won't work.

Also keep in mind that `emits` works only for a single step, meaning that the the parent can catch it. If you need to emit subchild -> child -> parent, then you should catch the event (using inline binding) from `subchild` **in** `child`, and re-emit it again so it goes to parent.

If it is outside of children-parent scope, then you should use what is called `a global bus`. Basically it narrows down everything to a single instance, which `emits` and `listens` for all events. So then they are no longer child-parent or whatever kind of connection, they are all on the very same instance, and therefore you can always use them in every component of yours.

Bottom line is - your approach to listen on mounted won't work. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between listening to each child and listening to the EventBus is this:

- when you emit an event like  `this.$emit('event') the event will be fired only for the parent component.`
- when you do a EventBus like `EventBus.$emit('event') then your event will be sent to all the components`

There are pros and cons for each one; EventBus can send events to components which will never use that event (can become an event polution), and the parent event emitter can be not that elegant to use as EventBus.

So you decide which approach is good for you.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Stumbled across this issue my self. Like the other said, when you want to bind an event listener from a parent, you need to use v-on because, well ... , you are binding something tot he child. So the actual callback is ran by the child, when that child detects that the event ocured.

In the child use `this.$parent.$emit('event-name');`
In the parent use

```
mounted: function() {
    this.$on('event-name', function() {console.log('test')});
}
```

The above will let you trigger the event in the parent so you can use $on in the parent to lsiten to that event that was triggered by the child.